# Android Database helper singleton and synchronize

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, singleton

I have created a DB helper using SQLiteOpenHelper. I have created the same in Singleton pattern to stop creating multiple the database object. As there is database operation from multiple threads, I maintain the object creation thread-safe, I make it synchronized.

```
    public class DatabaseManager{


    private static final String     DATABASE_NAME = "dbname";

    private static final int        DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DatabaseHelper   helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase   db;
    private Context          context;

    private DatabaseManager(Context c){
        this.context = c;
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
    }


    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private static volatile DatabaseManager instance;

    public static DatabaseManager getInstance(Context c){
    DatabaseManager r = instance;
    if (r == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {    // While we were waiting for the lock, another 
            r = instance;        // thread may have instantiated the object.
            if (r == null) {  
                r = new DatabaseManager();
                instance = r;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
   }




    public Cursor getAll() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = _openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            if (db == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return db.rawQuery("select * from todos order by priority, title", null);
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = _openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            if (db == null) {
                return;
            }
            db.delete("todos", "_id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
            db.close();
    }

    public long add(String title, int priority) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = _openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            if (db == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
            row.put("title", title);
            row.put("priority", priority);
            long id = db.insert("todos", null, row);
            db.close();
            return id;
    }

    public void update(long id, String title, int priority) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = _openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            if (db == null) {
                return;
            }
            ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
            row.put("title", title);
            row.put("priority", priority);
            db.update("todos", row, "_id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) } );
            db.close();
    }


    class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){            
                db.execSQL("create table todos (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text, priority integer)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

        }
    }
}
```

Now should I need to synchronized get(), add(), update(), delete() methods also for making them thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqliteDatabase is thread safe by default](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLockingEnabled(boolean)) so you should not synchronize the get, update and so on functions.

Also have a look at [SqliteDatabase synchronization](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html)

Btw you are virtually creating a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Why not just use `ContentProvider` class?